# How to use resolved variable in clojure

Tags: clojure

I can't manage to resolve a variable and use it. The problem seems trivial so most likely I missed it when reading the tutorials:

```
(def v 42)            ;=> #'user/v
(+ v 1)               ;=> 43
(+ (resolve 'v) 1)    ;ClassCastException clojure.lang.Var cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

However this works:

```
(defn w [] 4)         ;=> #'user/w
(+ (w) 1)             ;=> 5
(+ ((resolve 'w)) 1)  ;=> 5
```

Comment: you need to dereference it: `(+ @(resolve 'v) 1)` or `(+ (deref (resolve 'v)) 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @leetwinski why on earth didn't you make that an answer to the question?

Comment: @leetwinski please answer the question.

Comment: I applied the dupe hammer, because the answer to that question answers this one, though the wording is a little different. @Midiparse if you think this question needs a different answer let me know and I'll un-dupe it.

Comment: I think it's appropriate, that answers this one, no need for a duplicate answer.